# how to make interactive svg with apache batik?

Tags: svg, batik

My java app needs to create svg files with some hover texts and bit interactivity. Does batik have apis for this? I could see that rhino engine can be bundled with batik classes. But i believe it is for the java app 'displaying' svg in its own window. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You can find plenty of information about your question on the Internet. Just a few examples:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.batik.user/3811

http://batik.2283329.n4.nabble.com/Rendering-CSS-in-JSVGCanvas-td4470592.html

http://osdir.com/ml/text.xml.batik.user/2003-12/msg00185.html